# Python - Writing a function to calculate and return the area of a circle

Tags: python

The radius of the circle should be given as an argument to the function and the equation to calculate the area is PI*r2

```
area = PI*r2

def SetArea (myradius, myarea):
    PI = 3.14159
    myarea = PI*myradius *2

    return myarea
```

When I run the programme, the error appears as 'PI is not defined'

Comment: this is because of `area = PI*r2` line

Comment: you are calculating circumference of a circle not area. And function name `SetArea` not looks good ..i think `getArea()`  will be better

Answer (score 9):

Remove the first line of your program. It is that line that tries to access the global name `PI`, which is not defined. However, the line is not needed at all here.

Your function itself is fine, apart from not quite calculating the right value. To square a number, use `** 2`, not `* 2`.

Last, but not least, the Python `math` module has a [`math.pi` constant](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pi) you can use here:

```
import math

def calculate_area(radius):
    return math.pi * radius ** 2
```

Note that your function doesn't use or need a `myarea` argument either. I also renamed the function; since your function calculates the area and nothing is set, I thought `calculate_area()` would be a more descriptive name.

Comment: The function won't generate any syntax errors, but I wouldn't call it "fine". It doesn't calculate the area correctly and there is no need to pass in `myarea`.

Comment: Is this now correct? import math

def calculate_area(radius):
    return math.pi * radius ** 2
    PI = 3.14159
    calculate_area = PI*myradius **2

    return calculate_area

Comment: All you need is the code in my post; everything else is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def SetArea (myradius):
    myarea = math.pi * myradius ** 2
    return myarea
```

result

```
>>>print SetArea(1)
3.14159265359
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import function and the code leads as:

from math import pi
r = float(input ("Input the radius of the circle : "))
print ("The area of the circle with radius " + str(r) + " is: " + str(pi * r**2))

However, the answer containing only the input series seems to be missing on my part as well...